# Найти id, которые заработали больше других и в сумме заработали 60% денег

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

У меня есть таблица с данными и мне надо найти id, которые заработали больше других и в сумме заработали 60% денег. Таблица изначальна выглядела так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я посчитал заработанные деньги для каждого id и отсортировал их по возрастанию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как найти id, которые заработали больше других и в сумме заработали 60% денег

Comment: Вы можете привести примеры входных данных __в виде текста или выложить ссылку на файл__? Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-то так, хотя код не проверял:

```
# будем отсекать нижние 40% всех заработанных денег
sum40perc = df['sum'].sum() * 0.4

# считаем кумулятивную сумму денег
cumsum = df['sum'].cumsum()

# берём верхние 60% заработанных денег
df.loc[cumsum > sum40perc]
```